# How do you vertically and horizontally center a View with respect to another View that is at a higher zIndex (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, jsx

[Image of what I am envisioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo5NP.png)

I'm trying to add a center tick mark to a slider.

Is it possible to vertically and horizontally center View 1 with respect to View 2 and at the same time render View 2 above View 1 (using zIndex)? I can accomplish this by placing View 1 below View 2 in the Y direction and set the margin of View 1 so it appears underneath View 2 (in the Z direction). Is that the correct way to do this?

Accomplishing this by fiddling with the margins seems like it could cause problems on different size screens.

Comment: Does View2  have to be nested inside  View1? If not, you can create a containing view and just set have view1 and view2 have absolute positions to avoid having to tinker with the margin. Furthermore, doing it this way, you no longer need zIndex, as view2 will naturally be rendered on top of view1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving view1 and view2 absolute positions, and place them in a parent container that centers vertically and horizontally. This will allow them to overlap without having to play with margin, and will naturally place the view2 on top of view1 without having to use zIndex

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.specialContainer}>
        <View style={styles.tall}/>
        <View style={styles.long}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  specialContainer:{
     width:300,
     aspectRatio:1,
     backgroundColor:'pink',
     alignItems:'center',
     justifyContent:'center'
  },
  long:{
    position:'absolute',
    backgroundColor:'purple',
    width:'60%',
    height:24,
    // alignSelf:'center'
  },
  tall:{
    position:'absolute',
     backgroundColor:'green',
    height:'60%',
    width:24,
    // alignSelf:'center',
  }
});
```

Try it out [here](https://snack.expo.dev/HJVuqTB9l)

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the `View`s with a parent `View` like so:

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItem: 'center' }}>
  //horizontal
  <View style={{ zIndex: 1, elevation: 1, width: '100%', height: '20'% }}></View>
  //vertical
  <View style={{ zIndex: 0, elevation: 0, height: '100%', width: '20%' }}></View>
</View>
```

This will adjust dynamically depending on screen size since all height and width values are set using percentages.